# Code Coverage test for rust with visual studio code

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I have a problem with downloading the cargo tarpaulin in the VS code. When I run the cargo tarpaulin, it show an error parsing failed. I need help to fix it for my presentation.

[image: Here is the error]

I have tried to find the answer and asked some of my friends about it. I have downloaded some packages and it seems that one package is missing but I'm not sure.

Comment: Hello @mpeach, looks like you're new to stackoverflow, welcome! To improve your question, I recommend editing your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Currently your question doesn't really have enough details for anybody to provide much help.

Comment: In particular, could you share the (minimised, preferably with just one file of code) project and exact shell commands you execute to get this error? It'd also be helpful if you add the error as text, copied from terminal, and not as screenshot.